# How can I stop execution of a bash script, whether or not it's invoked with "source"?

Tags: bash

I am trying to get rid of an exit call in a bash script in order to make it sourceable.

At this moment the script contains an `exit` which is ok if you call the script normally, but if you source it, it will also stop the execution of the calling script which is not desired.

If I replace the `exit` with a `return` it will work well when source but it will fail with an error when is not sourced.

```
return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

I am looking at a solution what would work with both cases.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277275/156990

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the script's code in a function which you can then `return` from.

```
__main() {
    unset -f __main

    ...
    if whatever; then
        return
    fi
    ...
}

__main "$@"
```

Comment: Clear solution; another way is to make the opposite: only execute the relevant body "if NOT whatever"; it would not need the wrapper function - but it could be more complicated for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `return`, fall back to `exit` if it fails.

```
{ retval=$?; return "$retval" 2>/dev/null || exit "$retval"; }
```

Tested as follows:

```
cat >one <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "one starting"
source two
echo "one ending"
EOF

cat >two <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "two starting"
echo "two attempting to exit"
{ retval=$?; return "$retval" 2>/dev/null || exit "$retval"; }
echo "two still running after attempted exit
EOF

source one
```

...which properly/correctly emits:

```
one starting
two starting
two attempting to exit
one ending
```

...whereas running `chmod +x two; ./two` emits:

```
two starting
two attempting to exit
```

Comment: While this code make sense it does not seem to work when sourcing the function, the result being  a full exit.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that failure: If I put it in a file named `test-exit` and run `bash -c 'echo one; . test-exit; echo two'`, both `one` and `two` are present in output.

Comment: @sorin, ...see additions showing the test process I used. Do you get a different result? If so, with which release of bash?